# Highcharts plotOptions.series.compare='percent' renders blank

Tags: highcharts

Good evening. I am a newbie with the highcharts API. Currently i am displaying my data in a line graph. I have a checkbox that when selected i want it to show the percentage difference between the points in my graph instead of the values. I googled a lot, and i found out that changing the `series.compare='percent'` will do the work, but in my case instead of showing the % difference, it returns a white blank chart with no data or yaxis labels. Any advice?

[This is the initial rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUjVk.png)

[What happens in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azNyG.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhBVU.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/9657d8ze/22/

Comment: Could you reproduce your config and data in an online editor such as JSFiddle that we could work on?
Without seeing your exact code it’s hard to say what could be done. Here you can find a basic template: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/series-compare-percent/

Comment: Hello madepiet! Here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/9657d8ze/22/

i can not make compare="percent" to work

Comment: Could you please provide a simplified demo with full configuration of how it works exactly?
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g6zt8Lpq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, it was because i was putting the yAxis min value manually.